# EC2Box Auth fail when opening Composite SSH terminal

Tags: amazon-ec2

Thank you for writing EC2Box, it seems to be exactly the tool I can use to ssh into our EC2 instances. I created a new EC2 ubuntu instance to host EC2box. However I cannot get any of the Composite SSH Terminals to connect. I believe I have entered the account settings and keys correctly, and I can see the list of instances in the instances table. However, when I select any instance and click on the Create SSH Terminals button, I get an "Auth fail" error, and I see the following error on the EC2Box term:
    org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "HOST"; SQL statement:
    insert into system (display_nm, user, host, port, instance_id, key_id, region, state,   instance_status, system_status) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) [23502-175]

Do you know what could cause that?

thank you,
-John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks John!  When you have an instance that is shutdown the AWS services won't return a DNS for it and that was causing it to fail when inserting.  I never noticed that before. I actually just committed a fix and some other features.  I haven't done a release yet, but will get to it sometime today.

Comment: In my case ec2 instances are running still it's showing  "Auth fail" .....bty it's asking for password in spite of adding pem key ie private key furthermore I have also added my aws secret and access key also.

Comment: Enter password for Poc_DevOps_ubuntu_test - ( ec2-xxxxxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com ) ...................What password is it asking for I am not able to figure it out !

Comment: Oops by default it took user name as ec2-user which should be ubuntu in my case ......